# Aggadah Of Great Bird Destroying Towns

Tags: midrash, animals, agada-stories-legends, eggs, violence

I once heard about Jewish aggada telling about big bird throwing huge eggs made of steel which were destroying towns. Does anyone knows if there such aggada exists and what the source for it is?

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be looking for the Bar Yuchnei. [Talmud Bechoros 56b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=32&daf=57b&format=text):

> פעם אחת נפלה ביצת בר יוכני וטבעה ששים כרכים ושברה שלש מאות ארזים
>
> Once the Bar Yuchnei's egg fell and it flooded sixty cities and destroyed three hundred cedars.

The gemara there says that normally this wouldn't happen, but this particular egg was rotten so the bird threw it away.

It seems that there is another Jewish bird of such proportions called the ziz. Wikipedia quotes a book which attributes this gemara to the ziz; it seems that this might be a mistake of that author, or perhaps the birds are one and the same.

[Wikipedia Bar Yuchnei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_Juchne).

[Wikipedia Ziz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziz)

Comment: +1. While on the topic, the account [mentioned here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roc_%28mythology%29#Western_expansion) by [Binyamin of Tudela](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_of_Tudela) may be of interest. (Translation of מסעות בנימין found [here](http://www.teachittome.com/seforim2/seforim/masaos_binyomin_mitudela_with_english.pdf)).